# MySQL query very slow. Count(*) on indexed column

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, innodb

The table is in InnoDB table. Here is some information that might be helpful.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) AS y0_ FROM db.table this_ WHERE this_.id IS NOT NULL;

+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | this_ | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 4711235 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE db.table;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| id2          | varchar(28)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| photo        | longblob     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| source       | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| file_name    | varchar(120) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| file_type    | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| created_date | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_date | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| createdby    | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| updatedby    | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

The explain query gives me the result right there. But the actual query has been running for quite a while. How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

I basically need to figure out how many `photos` there are in this table. Initially the original coder had a query which checked `WHERE photo IS NOT NULL` (which took 3hours+) but I changed this query to check the `id` column as it is a primary key. I expected a huge performance gain there and was expecting an answer in under a second but that seems to not be the case.

What sort of optimizations on the database do I need to do? I think the query is fine but feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Edit: mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.52, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1

P.S: I renamed the tables for some crazy reason. I don't actually have the database named db and the table in question named table.

Comment: How does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db.table` perform? (Since `id` is non-null, it's equivalent to your current query.)

Comment: Bad. Takes over 10+minutes (I can't tell you for sure but thats how long I've waited).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How long is 'long'? How many rows are there in this table?

A MyISAM table keeps track of how many rows it has, so a simple COUNT(*) will always return almost instantly.

InnoDB, on the other hand works differently: an InnoDB table doesn't keep track of how many rows it has, and so when you COUNT(*), it literally has to go and count each row. If you have a large table, this can take a number of seconds.

EDIT: Try `COUNT(ID)` instead of `COUNT(*)`, where `ID` is an indexed column that has no NULLs in it. That *may* run faster.

EDIT2: If you're storing the binary data of the files in the longblob, your table will be massive, which will slow things down.

Possible solutions:

1. Use MyISAM instead of InnoDB.
2. Maintain your own count, perhaps using triggers on inserts and deletes.
3. Strip out the binary data into another table, or preferably regular files.

Comment: How long should InnoDB take on a 4.7million row table? The explain statement gives me my answer in under a second!

Comment: Yep, that's actually just an estimate! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Comment: I'm not sure how long a count query on 4.7m rows should take, because it will depend on other things like CPU speed, CPU load, etc, but maybe 5 seconds?

Comment: well lets just say it takes a lot more than 5 seconds. We're talking minutes / hours here. Even with `count(ID)`. I am using the innodb config file mysql provides (I could give it even more ram in the settings right now it has 1G). I have a server with 62G of ram and 4 cores. Something is clearly wrong.

Comment: Well that's strange. Is anything else thrashing the hard drive, or using up the CPU?

Comment: I mean I see the antivirus pop up here and there, although it shouldn't be scanning any of the database files since those are excluded. mysqld basically uses 100% of the cpu when this query is running and it takes forever! Are there any tmp folders or something mysql uses that I don't know about?

Comment: @Sanchit this is a good answer, don't get me wrong; but why did you 'accept' it if it did not solve your problem?

Comment: Well we figured out over chat that it seems like the (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26137/discussion-between-sanchit-and-aidan) logblob that is causing the performance hit. So option 2 seems like a good way to work around this problem. If this is in fact INCORRECT then feel free to enlighten the both of us.

Comment: Since we came up with a solution / he gave me a viable workaround I marked it answered. He atleast deserves a +1 from me for giving me over 30 minutes of his time. I'll give it a day before I mark this answer correct. I'll wait for other solutions as well then.

Comment: Using "COUNT(ID) instead of COUNT(*)" does not decrease the time. Quite contrary. Tested on very similar environment.

Comment: Did you solve it in the end by moving the longblob to another table? 
Doing the COUNT(ID) wouldn't help really (I believe so), because with that you're just getting the benefit of counting the indexed column (which is good, but not your main problem). Your main problem is in the "WHERE photo IS NOT NULL". That field is definitely NOT in the index (nor it should be), it is possibly huge and there are 5M of them. Hence - it's all slow, because with that WHERE condition you're making the table go through all those 5M fields and load all the blob values and check if they are NULL or not.

Comment: @userfuser He had already removed the `WHERE photo IS NOT NULL` clause and the query was still slow. To answer your question; yes, apparently moving the binary data out of the table made the query return in milliseconds.

Comment: thanks aidan. that slipped my mind. then apparently the whole table was a one big problem, when it comes to physically accessing it and reading from HDD.. which actually makes sense, since all the data of that table is just a single file on a HDD (when not in index).